# Best way to kill processes in a list

Tags: process, zsh

I've got this zsh script. Is there a more a graceful way to do this?

```
export PROCESSES_TO_QUIT='puma rake sidekiq spring rails ruby-debug phantomjs zeus passenger guard resque "node server.js"'

pgr() {
  echo "Finding processes in list: $PROCESSES_TO_QUIT"  
  for x in `echo ${PROCESSES_TO_QUIT}`; do 
    pgrep -fl $x;
  done 
}

pgk() {
  echo "Killing processes in list: $PROCESSES_TO_QUIT"  
  for x in `echo ${PROCESSES_TO_QUIT}`; do 
    pkill -fl $x;
  done 
}

pgkk() {
  echo "Killing -9 processes in list: $PROCESSES_TO_QUIT"  
  for x in `echo ${PROCESSES_TO_QUIT}`; do 
    pkill -9 -fl $x;
  done 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xargs` to separate them and execute `killall` for each one :

`echo $PROCESSES_TO_QUIT | xargs killall -9`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `killall`:

```
% export PROCESSES_TO_QUIT='puma rake ...'
% export KILL_SIGNAL='killall -9 '
% eval $KILL_SIGNAL $PROCESSES_TO_QUIT
```

Comment: @G-Man, the edits you made do not work for zsh on my system: e.g., `processname1, processname2: no process found`.  Let (AT)justingordon to evaluate the suggestion in this form.

Comment: Why killall and not pkill? I'm not sure that my list would match the process names automatically. Might, but might not.

Comment: I'm [pretty sure](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27501/whats-the-difference-between-killall-and-pkill#27504) killall is just pkill+grep combined.  Different strokes for different folks, but with the right options they get the same things done.